# How to save python outputs from container to host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

[image]

My project directory looks like this, I run docker-compose that builds a dockerfile inside a subdirectory. Inside the dockerfile I'm executing `RUN python3 Preprocessing.py` the file transform the raw data into preprocessed data and saves to a new file (it's in read in the picture) `df.to_csv('./data/preprocessed_dataset.csv')` I've been trying to link the volumes of the host and container to be able to see the preprocessed file but could not achieve that. I'm not able to see the output file on my computer.
I tried this in docker-compose:

```
volumes:
      - ./data:/data
```

Comment: A Docker container, by design, needs special setup to access host files.  You can't do it from a Dockerfile to build a host-independent reusable image.  Would it make more sense to run this process in a virtual environment, without a container?

Comment: You are on the right path by using volumes. I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, but it seems that you are mounting the volume in a path and saving the file on another path... The python process working directory seems to be the "subFolder" and the docker-compose context is the project root...